# Join tables via doctrine find

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to use the EntityManager to load all fields from a table as well as its associations, here's my (test) scenario: I have the entity user and the entity user_post, and the user can have several user_post.

user:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/** @ORM\Entity */
class user
{

/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
public $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="user_post", mappedBy="id_user", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE, fetch="EAGER")
 */
public $posts;

/**
 * @var string $author
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
 */
public $author;

/**
 * @var text $content
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", nullable=false)
 */
public $content;

/**
 * @var text $createdAt
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="text", nullable=false)
 */
public $createdAt;

public function __construct() {
    $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
}

}
```

user_post:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/** @ORM\Entity */
class user_post
{

/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
public $id;

/**
 * @var integer $id_user
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="user", inversedBy="posts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
 */
public $id_user;

/**
 * @var text $content
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", nullable=false)
 */
public $content;


}
```

I'm using public variables to be easier to debug.

Now, I'm trying:

```
$user = $doctrine->em->find('user', 2);
```

I get the user object ok, however instead the user_post object it returns:

```
Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection Object ( [snapshot:Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection:private] => Array ( [0] => user_post Object ( [id] => 1 [id_user] => user Object *RECURSION*
```

And doesn't return the actual data. Also it returns a giant array.

Is there a way to get all the data with the find function?

Comment: How are you generating that output? can you show us that code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$posts` property is mapped as a `OneToMany`, which means that a `user` will have *many* `user_post`.

Therefore `$posts` is hydrated as a *collection* of `user_post` objects, which contains the objects you expect:

```php
$user = $doctrine->em->find('user', 2);

foreach ($user->posts as $post) {
    echo $post->content;
}
```